# Why aren't AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction's being applied?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I am using AVAssetExportSession to concatenate several video recordings into a single entry.

As the user can switch between front and rear camera during the recording, the orientation of the recordings switches such that if a recording comprises of one clip using the forward facing camera and a second using the rear, then the concatenated video will show the first clip using the expected orientation and the second upside down (or vice versa).

I know I need to set the videoComposition instructions on the exporter, but I have had no joy in getting any rotations to be applied to the exported video.

In the example below, I am setting a dummy rotation transform of 90 degrees, just to try and force a change across the board, but my exported video is unaffected . . . I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see what, can anyone see my mistake?

```
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVAssetExportSession *assetExport = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    NSMutableArray *instructions = [NSMutableArray new];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    CGAffineTransform transformToApply=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0);

    for (NSURL *path in filePaths) {
        NSLog(@"%@", path);
        AVURLAsset *asset =[AVURLAsset assetWithURL:path];

        CMTime atTime = composition.duration;
        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                                       ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                                        atTime:atTime error:&error];

        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]];
        [layerInstruction setTransform:transformToApply atTime:kCMTimeZero];            
        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * videoTrackInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
        videoTrackInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(atTime, asset.duration);
        videoTrackInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
        [instructions addObject:videoTrackInstruction];

        [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                                       ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
                                        atTime:atTime error:&error];
    }
    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComposition.instructions = instructions;
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, compositionVideoTrack.naturalTimeScale);
    videoComposition.renderSize = compositionVideoTrack.naturalSize;
    assetExport.videoComposition = videoComposition;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schoolboy error, the transform should be radians, not degrees - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html